# Construir instaladores para windows mac y linux electron

Tags: nodejs, linux, windows, macos, electron

Estoy haciendo una aplicación desktop, y lo que quiero es poder construir instaladores para las 3 plataformas.

Estoy usando electron builder, pero tengo el problema de que solo me permite construir aplicaciones para la misma plataforma. Si es Windows para Windows, linux para linux y mac para mac, ya que al construir los ejecutables desde linux hacia Windows me sale un error de aplicación no válida.

Viendo el hilo en GitHub sobre el tema, recomiendan construir en el mismo sistema operativo, para el caso de mac, no me permite construir los instaladores.

¿Cómo podría construir los instaladores? Lo deseo para luego construirlas en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: *"pero tengo el problema de que solo me permite construir aplicaciones para la misma plataforma"*. Justamente esa es la idea. Si bien es posible, es también muy probable te encuentres con problemas de dependencias debido a la plataforma. Lo mejor es empaquetar estando en la plataforma destino.

Comment: @KevinAB por favor, tengamos cuidado al crear nuevas etiquetas en el sitio.